# Symbol in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm newbie in linear algebra and I do not understand the symbol that is selected with blue color.

What does this symbol means?
What is the purpose to use this symbol?
What context is this symbol being used?
Why do you use this symbol?

[image]

Comment: It is like a little "e" and means "element of", so "o with a bar" is an element of the set S. But really, you are on the wrong site...  this is for users of Mathematica (the software), so your question will probably be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example that you can show me in a practical approach?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)

Comment: The symbol $\in$ is not specific to linear algebra, but is in fact widely used in mathematics.

Comment: By the way, is it $\overrightarrow{o}$ (vector "o") or $\overrightarrow{0}$ (the zero vector)? I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 2):

it means

```
O is an element of S.
```

Answer (score 1):

When it says $\vec{0}\in S$ what it means is "The zero or null vector in the space $S$"

Answer (score 0):

The $\in$ symbol refers to an ${element}$ or member of a particular set. Thus the expression $\vec{0}\in S$ translates to "the zero vector is an element of the vector space $ S $".